# Option "infoFiltered" does not work on my datatable

Tags: javascript, datatable, datatables

I have datatables in my program. The "infoFiltered" option works on some of them, but not on all... Do you know why ?

[image]

Comment: Please add code as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), and not as [screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: Can you show us enough code and data to allow us to recreate your problem?

Comment: You can also take the [tour] and read [ask] for more guidance on writing a good question. You can also read the guidelines for creating a [mre].